# Can't seem to push to GitHub using magit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I am attempting to push to a GitHub repository using Magit on Emacs 24.3.1.  Note, I'm on a Windows box.

I have staged and committed changes to a file and M-x magit-status reflects only untracked files that are resident to my clone of the repo.

To push, from the Magit status buffer, I do `P P` and the message I get is:

```
Running c:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe push -v origin master
```

It seems to hang here and no further activity is evident.  When I go to push from the command line, everything seems fine and I am prompted for my GitHub username:

```
PS H:\.emacs.d> git push -v origin master
Pushing to https://github.com/Username/emacs.d
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I have set `user.name` using `git config`, but apparently this is not preventing git from prompting me for my username at the command line.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong here and how I can get Magit to push?

Comment: try changing the remote to use `ssh` instead of `https`. Also, is there anything in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: Nothing in the `*Messages*` buffer.  Will try `ssh`.

Comment: When I switched to `ssh://github.com/Username/emacs.d.git`, I got `Permission denied (publickey).` in the `*magit-process*` buffer.  Note, that I also receive the same message from cmd line.

Comment: Easiest solution is to create / add a public key to your github user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user.name` is only for authorship of commits, and *not* used for authentication.   I wonder how you got this idea, given that no such feature is documented.

The username for authentication must be set explicitly, via [git-credentials](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html).  In case of Github, add the following to your Git configuration:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    username = johndoe
```

Where `johndoe` is to be replaced with your real user name, obviously.

I'd recommend you to use SSH, though.  Generate an SSH keypair, add the public key to Github, and use `git@github.com:johndoe/myrepo.git` instead of `https://github.com/johndoe/myrepo.git` as remote.  Together with Putty's auth agent, you'll be able to push without any further password prompts after adding your key once to the agent.

You'll also be able to use different keys for different systems, and revoke each key independently from others, and from your Github password.  Furthermore, SSH keys cannot be used to login on Github itself, so even if your keys get lost your Github account is still mostly safe.  All in all, SSH keys are much safer, especially on systems that are at a risk of getting lost or stolen, e.g. laptops.

Comment: Thank!  Incidentally, is MsysGit and MsysSSH the best way to go about using SSH for git on Windows?

Comment: @PatternMatching I am sorry, but I do not know.  I was under the impression that Git on Windows could use Putty, which is arguably the best SSH client for Windows, but then I never really used Git itself (or Emacs) on Windows.  It's long since I worked on Windows, and back then I used Git Extensions, and later, briefly SourceTree.

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix:

`(setenv "GIT_ASKPASS" "git-gui--askpass")`

Check this: https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/FAQ#windows-cannot-push-via-https